# How to add special condition to bind_param?

Tags: php, mysqli

I have an `array` with topics and which I generate attributes to add to the query and to the `bind_param`:

```
   $arr = explode(',', $theme);
   $strMarcas  = str_repeat('?,', count($arr) - 1) . '?';
   $strTipos = str_repeat('s', count($arr));
```

For example usage:

```
   WHERE main_cover in ($strMarcas)
```

And in the `bind_param`:

```
   $stmt->bind_param($strTipos, ...$arr);
```

Now the problem is that I need to pass other conditions to the `WHERE` example:

```
   WHERE main_cover in ($strMarcas) AND language=? AND active=?
```

And, I don't know how to pass the conditions, I already tried this:

```
   $stmt->bind_param($strTipos . "si", ...$arr, $language, $active);
```

And, that generates this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot use positional argument after argument unpacking

Comment: Bind your arguments in a different order

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular I don't understand, I do it backwards

Comment: @TangentiallyPerpendicular It's just that if I do the order differently, I have other subqueries with where and I can't change the order.

Comment: Using an ORM can help abstract over the problem to make it easier to solve.  But generally with this kind of thing, you should dynamically create the `?`'s in the query then dynamically bind to it. This way you can have an array with keys and values, then dynamically produce the sql string with the question marks, then loop through it again and bind one at a time so it matches your array structure.

Comment: @KevinY I see that I have to combine the array and increase the other.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Can you do something like this?

Instead of:

```
$stmt->bind_param($strTipos . "si", ...$arr, $language, $active);
```

which errors with:

> Fatal error: Cannot use positional argument after argument unpacking

Can you append to the array before you try to bind it?

```
$ar[] = $language;
$ar[] = $active;
$stmt->bind_param($strTipos . "si", ...$arr);
```

If that doesn't work, can you make a temporary array by looping through the values, then append the last 2, then bind the temporary array instead?

Answer (score 1):

Why use `bind_param()` at all?

Just pass the array to `execute()`

```
$stmt->execute($arr);
```